# How to add custom JS file in Wordpress Child theme with get_theme_file_uri

Tags: themes, child-theme

I just want to add a custom JS file in WordPress Child Theme underneath the parent script JS without using  **wp_dequeue_script()** or **wp_deregister_script()**.

I just Want to use the latest function **get_theme_file_uri()**.

Child theme **functions.php** code is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Child Theme Functions
 *
 * @package Anyname
 * @subpackage Anyname Child
 * @since 1.0.0 
 */

if( ! function_exists( 'anyname_child_theme_setup' ) ) :

    // Child Theme Setup 
    function anyname_child_theme_setup() {

        load_child_theme_textdomain( 'anyname-child', get_theme_file_path( '/languages' ) );

    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'anyname_child_theme_setup' );

if( ! function_exists( 'anyname_child_enqueue_scripts' ) ) :

    // Child Enqueue Scripts
    function anyname_child_enqueue_scripts() {

        $anyname_parent_theme_style = 'parent-anyname-style';
        $anyname_parent_theme_script = 'parent-anyname-script'; 

        wp_enqueue_style( $anyname_parent_theme_script, get_parent_theme_file_uri( '/style.css' ) );

        wp_enqueue_style( 'anyname-child-style',
            get_theme_file_uri( '/style.css' ),
            array( $anyname_parent_theme_style ),
            wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
        );

        // wp_enqueue_script( $anyname_parent_theme_script, get_parent_theme_file_uri( '/anyname.js' ) );

        // wp_enqueue_script( 'anyname-child-script',
        //     get_theme_file_uri( '/js/script.js' ),
        //     array( $anyname_parent_theme_script ),
        //     wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
        // );

         wp_enqueue_script( 'anyname-child-script',
            get_theme_file_uri( '/js/child-script.js' ),
            array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/child-script.js' ) ), true );

    }

endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'anyname_child_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Have you enqueued the script without that function?

Comment: hi, the child theme custom script file is showing the top of all script files. but is it possible to transfer it underneath the bottom of all script files like child style sheet? Thanks In Advanced.

Comment: Can you include the current code you're using in the question?

Comment: The question is edited and I've added the code. Please, check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your script to load after a specific script, you need to set it as a dependency. You set the dependency of scripts by using the 3rd argument of [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

In your case it appears that you want to enqueue `anyname-child-script` after `parent-anyname-script`. To do that you need to enqueue the child theme script like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'anyname-child-script',
    get_theme_file_uri( '/js/child-script.js' ),
    array( 'parent-anyname-script' ), // The line that has changed.
    filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/child-script.js' ) ),
    true
);
```

You'll notice that to do this properly you need to know the handle used for the parent theme's script.

If you don't know the name, then you can cause your scripts to load later by using a larger number for priority when hooking into `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'anyname_child_enqueue_scripts', 50 );
```

The `50` there means that your scripts will be enqueued after any scripts that are enqueued at a number lower than `50` (the default is `10`).

This is not a very reliable method though, as things like dependencies can cause scripts to load later than their priority. The only truly reliable way to make sure your script loads after another script is to make it a dependency.